# Composition of Partially Ordered Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Prove or disprove: If $R$ and $S$ are partial orderings on $A$, then $R \circ S$ is a partial ordering on $A$.

I started out defining $R$ and $S$ but I am unsure how to use the definition of partially ordered sets to prove that the composition of the two are also partially ordered. Also one thing I have been thinking is how can you guarantee the composition of these two exist?

Comment: Composition of relations on a given set is always defined. In fact, the first thing you should do is look up the definition of composition of relations. Be careful, there are two conventions, so you need to know which one is used for your class or textbook. Also, it's a prove or disprove, so don't automatically assume it's something to be proved. You should test it against using a small test case.

Comment: Im thinking the reflexive property fails. if $(x,y) \in S$ then $(y,x) \in R$ for the composition to work but that would fail to be partially ordered? @quasi

Comment: So all you need is a small counterexample. How about a 2-element set A? Disproofs are often easier than proofs. The claim for this question seemed dubious on a number of counts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter example 
Take $A = \{1, 2, 3 \}$

$R = \{ (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 2)\}$

$S = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (3, 1), (2, 1)\}$

$S \circ R = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)\}$

But $S \circ R$ is not **antisymmetric**
So it's not a partial order

Answer (score 0):

Here $R \subseteq AXA$  and   $S \subseteq AXA$ are the two relations .. now composition $S \circ R$ is defined by 
$ (a, b) \in S \circ R \iff  \exists$ $x \in  A$ such that $(a, x) \in R \land (x, b) \in S$
.. use this as definition .. and after that every thing falls in place automatically ..

Comment: Er... does everything fall into place, though?

Comment: No .. but he will get the idea.   Where the problem lies.   Antisymmetry and transitivity